# Unable to display API data on frontend - Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, ionic-framework

I am a beginner in both Ionic and APIs. Currently, I have an API where I need to get data and display it on my app. I am able to get the data in Array format and am having troubles displaying it. I tried to change the data format to JSON but to no avail. I have also tried to display the data using the *ngFor but it doesn’t work as well. Will anyone please guide me on this?

The data I see in console.log is in this format (I attached the code for one record):

```
{resource_id: Array(1), limit: 100, total: "62", records: Array(62)}
limit: 100
records: Array(62)
1:
dedicated_date: "1900-01-01T00:00:00"
dedicated_time: "00:00:00"
dedication_id: 4
location: "some text"
message: "some text"
other_song_request: ""
phone_no:"1234567"
pledge_amount: 300
remain_anon: 0
sing_to: "some text
sing_to_department: "some text"
song: "some text"
special_request: ""
status: ""
```

I also see this on my console log:

```
hello
Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: 
Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}
closed: false
destination: SafeSubscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, 
_subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, …}
isStopped: false
syncErrorThrowable: false
syncErrorThrown: false
syncErrorValue: null
_parent: null
_parents: null
_subscriptions: []
__proto__: Subscription
```

…/providers/christmas

```
getDedi() {
   return Observable.create(observer => 
  this.http.get<DediResult>(`${this.dataApiUrl}?//some api
    { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', this.getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN'))})
    .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    /*observer.next(true);
    observer.complete();*/
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
    observer.next(false);
    observer.complete();
  })
)
```

}

admin.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-admin',
  templateUrl: 'admin.html'
})
export class AdminPage {

  dedi: Dedi[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
NavParams, public christmasProvider: ChristmasProvider, private storage: 
Storage) {
    console.log('constructor Testpage');
  }

  gotoDetailspage(dedi){
    this.navCtrl.push(DetailPage, {dedi: dedi});
  }

   ionViewDidLoad(){
console.log('ionViewDidLoad Testpage');

const dedicator = this.christmasProvider.getDedi().subscribe(dedid => {
  this.dedi = dedid;
});
console.log('hello', dedicator);
  }      
}
```

admin.html

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu" style="color: #fff"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <ion-title>
        <p class="header">ADMIN</p>
      </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>

  <br><br><br>
  
  <ion-content padding>
      <h6>DEDICATION:</h6>
        <ion-item *ngFor ="let d of dedid " (click) = gotoDetailspage()>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col align-self-start style="text-align: left;">
              <p>{{ d.song }}</p> 
              <p>{{ d.pledge_amount }}</p> 
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-content>
```

../models/songdedi

```js
export interface DediData {
    data: DediResult;
}

export interface DediResult {
    result: DediRecords;
}

export interface DediRecords {
    records: Dedi[];
}

export interface Dedi {
    dedication_id: string;
    pledge_amount: number;
    phone_no: number;
    sing_to: string;
    sing_to_department: string;
    dedicated_date: string;
    song: string;
    other_song_request: string;
    special_request: string;
    status: string;
    location: string;
    message: string;
    remain_anon: string;
}
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

seems like you're declared variable `dedi` was not used on `admin.html`, and instead you used the incorrect one which is `dedid`.

```
// Change the get dedi function into this
getDedi() {
    return this.http.get<DediResult>(`${this.dataApiUrl}?//some api
    { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', this.getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN'))});
)

// and In your admin.ts
ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.christmasProvider.getDedi().pipe(
        map((dediResult: DediResult) => dediResult && dediResult.result.records)
    ).subscribe(dedid => {
        this.dedi = dedid;
    });
};
```

Comment: dedid was what i subscribed to. I shouldn't use the variable i subscribed to on html? I tried changing it to dedi as well but it doesn't work too.

Comment: because you need to execute the `dedicator` delegate inorder to execute the subscribe of the observable. try removing the const dedicator, I also found some issues here on the `getDedi()` method, you don't need to wrap the `http.get` method into observable because it is already an observable

Comment: sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. can you give me an example?

Comment: I've updated the answer together with the code, try to use that one

Comment: tried it and I got an error message. It is coming from admin.ts, under 'this.dedi',  saying: 
[ts] Type 'DediResult' is not assignable to type 'Dedi[]'.

[ts] Type 'DediResult' is not assignable to type 'Dedi[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type 'DediResult'.

Comment: may I see the DediResult model? we need to map it on the response.

Comment: I posted it together with the question, the last block of codes (../models/songdedi). Thanks a lot for your help btw :)

Comment: I am so sorry but it is still throwing errors :( This time, 'map' and 'this.dedi' are throwing errors. For 'map', the error is '[ts] Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'? any'. (I have also imported import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; but this doesn't solve the issue).

Comment: For 'this.dedi', it is throwing 2 errors. '[ts] Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Dedi[]'.

[ts] Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Dedi[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'. this: this'.

Sorry for troubling you

Comment: try adding this line to your admin.ts `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: oh that worked! however, i tried running the codes and i get this ' ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'records' of undefined'. Actually, i always get this whenever i try to use map. Do you know why?

Comment: yes, because the result variable was undefined, it's either the whole response is undefined or the result field only is undefined.

Comment: it's something related on how you construct your model based on the `getDedi()` response.

Comment: meaning it's an issue with either my provider or model? not admin.ts right?

Comment: yeah it's an issue on your model, the model your mapping with should be the same as the model of the response from API; including the casing and the type, they all should be the same.